# Notation for matrix indexing in Math .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math, math.net

When using a DenseMatrix from Math .NET, and I want to access the second column, third row, do I write `matrix[1,2]` or `matrix[2,1]` in other words, does the first index determine the row or the column?

Comment: matrix[2,1], row first and then the column (syntax is the same as At() method, it follows math standard conventions).

Comment: Thank you both. I could have tested this on my own, and I realize it's easily answered with a test, but I asked the question to spare others the trouble - this is information that should be stated clearly on the web, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search yields this documentation:

http://api.mathdotnet.com/Numerics/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseMatrix.htm

While it's lacking in what you're asking, it does have a RowCount property you can interrogate to find your answer.

*Running a test now*

---

It's `[row, column]`.

```
public virtual T this[int row, int column]
{
    get
    {
        RangeCheck(row, column);
        return At(row, column);
    }

    set
    {
        RangeCheck(row, column);
        At(row, column, value);
    }
}
```